# Argument types do not match parameters, when trying to dispatch a parameter-less async thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

Below is the warning I get when trying to dispatch this thunk inside of one of my components. Not sure why this is happening because my thunk does not require any parameters.
[image: Dispatch]

This is my thunk that I am trying to dispatch which returns all of the names as an array from a json file that I made. This thunk does return the correct information.As you can see there is no need for any other data to be passed through.

[image: Thunk]

The only thing that the slice needs to handle for this thunk is the promise lifecycle and data to set which I effectively do. The state parameter should be automatically handled and the action is passed by through the return of my thunk (at least to my understanding).

[image: Reducer]

If you need any more information please let me know, not sure what additional thing would come in handy as of this moment.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. Please create [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of screenshots

Comment: Actually, all of the code works correctly, I believe that it is a problem with the IDE I use. A bug or whatever you might call it.

Comment: @korpe i'm using webstorm and getting this issue. VSCode all good... did you find a fix?

Comment: i went into my webstorm typescript config, and i found that my node interpreter was not set. setting this fixed my issue.